# ng-include doesn't work when ng-app gets a name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using ng-include to include a navbar. In combination with ng-app="" it works fine.But when I use a name (e.g. ng-app="myApp") then it doesn't work anymore. See example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body >
        <div ng-app="">
        <div ng-include="'pages/navbar.html'"></div>
            <script src="app.js"</script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
   });
```

This above works fine, but when I insert the name "myApp" it stops including the navbar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body >
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-include="'pages/navbar.html'"></div>
            <script src="app.js"</script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Why?**

Comment: you need to change the reference by closing the script tag `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Comment: which version of angular are you using?  `ng-app=""` isn't valid in most of the recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here

```
<script src="app.js"</script>
```

It should be

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

As long as this loads after angular.js then your application should be able to find the declaration of the myApp module (which you've asked it to by using `ng-app="myApp"`

Check in the browser console for any errors - if the script isn't loaded you will see an error like `cannot find module`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have missed including your `app.js` file in a proper style.
are you getting any error in console?

Edited

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body >
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-include="'pages/navbar.html'"></div>

        </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're including the script twice

Comment: Funny thing is that it works on local host with live example from brackets. But starting it from the explorer gives no result at all.